# ¿Como convertir el mes de la fecha a texto?

Tags: sql, sql-server

quiero que mis meses que están numéricos se muestren en texto ,pero no se no la forma correcta de utilizar el datename. Gracias

```
 SELECT SUM(AU.Tarifa_Diaria) AS [TOTAL],MONTH (AO.fTermino) AS [MES]
 FROM Arriendo_Autos AU INNER JOIN Arriendo_Solicitud AO
 ON AU.Patente = AO.Patente
 GROUP BY MONTH (AO.fTermino)
```

Comment: Hola Daniela. Aqui ayudamos con los problemas concretos, no con las tareas. Eso significa que has de mostrar lo que has intentado y de no haberlo intentado lo que has investigado. Despues explicar qué duda  o problema tienes.  Sin ello sería como estar pidiendo que te hagamos los deberes. Mira [ask] y [mcve] para mejorar la pregunta y pulsa en [edit] para añadir la informacion que falta. Un saludo

Comment: ¿Qué DBMS estás usando (Oracle, MySQL, SQL Server, PostgreSQL, FileMaker...)? ¿Cuando dices que se muestren en texto qué quieres decir, los nombres de los meses en castellano?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Efectivamente, puedes valerte de la función [`datename`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datename-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017), que se utilizaría de la siguiente manera

```
SELECT   SUM(AU.Tarifa_Diaria) AS [TOTAL]
       , datename (month, AO.fTermino) AS [MES]
  FROM Arriendo_Autos AU 
       INNER JOIN Arriendo_Solicitud AO ON AU.Patente = AO.Patente
 GROUP BY datename(month, AO.fTermino)
```

En el primer parámetro de `datename`, además de `month` puedes utilizar los valores `year`, `quarter`, `day`, `week`, `weekday`, entre otros.

El resultado quedaría algo como:

```
TOTAL                                   MES
--------------------------------------- ------------------------------
1.0                                     Enero

(1 row(s) affected)
```

Answer (score 0):

Utiliza el `convert` para convertir el valor al tipo de dato que desea es decir tu código debería quedar así,

```
 SELECT 
     SUM(AU.Tarifa_Diaria) AS [TOTAL],
     CONVERT(VARCHAR,MONTH(AO.fTermino)) AS [MES]
 FROM Arriendo_Autos AU INNER JOIN Arriendo_Solicitud AO
 ON AU.Patente = AO.Patente
 GROUP BY MONTH (AO.fTermino)
```

Espero que te funcione